# AG Grid React Enterprise License issue

Tags: ag-grid, durandal, ag-grid-react

I am using the AG Grid React for a project & the free version seems to be working fine. Recently i got a trial license & tried to incorporate that with the Ag Grid React. I have followed the following approach for importing the license

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import {LicenseManager} from "ag-grid-enterprise";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("license key");
```

Some features of Ag Grid Community & Ag Grid are also getting used as below

```
import { GridOptions, ColDef, ColGroupDef, ICellRendererParams } from "ag-grid";
import { CellClickedEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';
```

After that the Ag Grid shows up just fine like before but the enterprise features are still missing. I have tried to import the license at application starting point as well but still no luck.

There is no console error or warning for missing enterprise licence etc.

The Project is Durandal based front end application that leverages Require.js & Grunt minification.
Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just import the enterprise version

```
import "ag-grid-enterprise";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
import { LicenseManager } from 'ag-grid-enterprise/main';
```

You can import cellClickedevent from ag-grid

```
import { CellClickedEvent } from 'ag-grid'
```